# Calling jquery plugin from .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have a custom control which is used on many pages. I am making use of a jQuery plugin shown in the below link.
Link- http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-custom-select-box-plugin/

Problem is this plugin loads on the pages which take time to load and fails on those which load quickly.I also have multiple instances of this plugin on the same pages. I have tried calling the plugin in two different ways as listed below. But it is making no difference.I am doing everything in .cs file. I don't have aspx or ascx file.

01)

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "dropdownchecklistOrg-setup" +   
this.GetHashCode(), string.Format("$(document).ready(function() {{ $('#{0}').custSelectBox();}});", listBox.ClientID), true);
```

02)

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "dropdownchecklistOrg-setup" + this.GetHashCode(), string.Format("$('#{0}').custSelectBox();", listBox.ClientID), true);
```

I get the below error on the pages which are loaded quickly.

```
$('#ctl00_FullRegion_MainRegion_EditForm_PredefinedLocations_DropdownCheckList').custSelectBox() is not a function.
```

Please suggest what can be done to fix this.

Thanks

***Edit***

This issue was due to different versions of jQuery library being loaded. I had 3 plugins on the same page. 1 plugin was loading jQuery 1.42 version and the other 2 plugins were loading jQuery 1.32 version.If the 1.42 version was loaded at start up the other two plugins would fail to work.

Comment: I don't understand, how have you not got aspx or ascx file?

Comment: What do the generated HTML page look like?

Comment: This is for a CMS where in I am adding a custom property type(which functions as a muliple select dropdown). Once I get this undefined error, if I refresh the page the pulgin does load. But in some pages on initial load it fails.Adding $(document).ready is also not helping. Is there any other way by which I can check if the scripts have finished loading completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to different versions of jQuery library being loaded. I had 3 plugins on the same page. 1 plugin was loading jQuery 1.42 version and the other 2 plugins were loading jQuery 1.32 version.If the 1.42 version was loaded at start up the other two plugins would fail to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just a typo, but in your code for 01, it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#{0}').custSelectBox(); });
```

and not

```
$(document).ready(function() {{ $('#{0}').custSelectBox();}});
```

Comment: No, I will need double {{ }} when using string.format otherwise it will give invalid string error.